# iOS 14 Text() with timer for Days

Tags: text, timer, swiftui, widget, ios14

I am building a widget in iOS 14 to countdown the days until an event. I want the timer to have Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. So far I have found that the `Text(someFutureDate, style: .timer)` works (almost) perfectly. The only downside is that it only counts `hours:minutes:seconds`.

Currently, the next event in my application is 79 days away so displaying 1,915 hours isn't the most user friendly thing to do. Does anyone have a clever trick to displays `days:hours:minutes:seconds`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives you "2 days, 3 hours" in the Text.

```
let components = DateComponents(day: 2, hour: 3, minute: 4, second: 5)
let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())!
Text(futureDate, style: .relative)
```

The Text displays only two date components at any one time. Once days drop to zero, the label changes to "X hours, Y minutes", and once hours drop to zero, the label changes to "X minutes, Y seconds" Apple handles the format of the time in the Text label, so you can't modify the formatting beyond the styling (.relative/.offset/.timer).

Answer (score 0):

have a view were you can append days and timer like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let days: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack { 
          Text(days)
          Text(":")
          Text(Date(), style: .timer)
        }
    }
}
```

you can use TimelineProvider and make the widget to update on every midnight

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
       let dayremaining = 10 // your day from main app
       let midnight = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).startOfDay(for: Date())
       let timeline = Timeline(entries: [ContentView(days:dayremaining)], policy: .after(midnight))

    }
```